# View which filters based on URL matching field value

Tags: 7, views

I'm trying to create a view for solr search results, what I'd like to do is have have a page in the view each of which pull data from the same set of results but filter them based on matching part of the URL to a field in the content type being indexed.

The problem is the part of the URL used for matching won't match the value of the field in content type, so I was thinking of having a list of some sort which would match the URL with the corresponding field value.

Is this even possible? If it's not I could always create a new view page for each possible URL & manually set a filter criteria. I was just hoping that rather than creating multiple view pages I could do it with one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to do exactly what I wanted but what I did instead was create an exposed filter for the field in the content type being searched & use the URL parameter it created when in use to filter search results.

The exposed form itself is hidden with CSS as just including the filter without exposing it won't allow it to be activated via a URL parameter.